# how to make text gray if switch is off in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Hi here i have on off switch, if the switch is on TEXT should be normal black color, else TEXT should be red color, Some one help me out in this

FIDDLE:
  http://jsfiddle.net/0o88p8xy/

```
     **Html code**
       <section>
                  <label>Award of excelence</label>
                  <div class="onoffswitch">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" class="SwitchOn" value="all"  
                  checked>
                    <label for="radio1"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" class="SwitchOff"  
              value="false">

                    <label for="radio2"></label>
                  </div>
                </section>

                <section>
                  <label>Innovation Index</label>
                  <div class="onoffswitch">
                    <input type="radio" id="radios21" name="radios2" class="SwitchOn" value="all"
              checked>
                    <label for="radios21"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="radios22" name="radios2" class="SwitchOff" 
                value="false">
                    <label for="radios22"></label>
                  </div>
                </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some leads :

1. Use the [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive to bind your switches to a boolean property of the `$scope`(so you will need a controller for that).
2. Use the [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive to reflect the value of that boolean property by having a variable class on the text element.